# Prevent Outlook 2013 Addin deactivation

Tags: c#, outlook, registry, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I am developing an AddIn for Outlook.
Outlook 2013 deactivates AddIns if they take to long to start.
As i am writing my AddIn in C#, it the .Net Enviroment needs to be loaded and that takes time. The actual startup of the AddIn is very fast.

Depending on the hardware i may exceed the 1sec limit of Outlook on which the AddIn gets deactivated.

You can prevent the an AddIn from deactivation with an Registry Entry in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

My Problem is in finding the right moment to write this Registry Entry.

- At the start of the AddIn doesn't work as it may never get so far.
- At the time of the installation, i can set the entry only for those users who already logged in to that particular pc.
- As i am also running an service under local machine at the same pc, i could regularly update the Registry of any new user. But i would still have the problem when a Users uses that pc for the first time.
- Writing the entry to the local machine registry doesn't seam to work either, as at least in my test, the missing key wasn't copied but a new one was created.

Do you have any ideas on how to prevent Outlook from disabling the AddIn
or when to write registry entry?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any ideas on how to prevent Outlook from disabling the AddIn or when to write registry entry?

I'd suggest working on the startup time of your add-in instead. Move any initialization code to another threads and make the main thread free letting Outlook running without delays. In that case you will not have to add the windows registry key.

Comment: the startup time of my code is about 10ms, loading the .Net enviroment takes too long at bad hardware

Comment: You are free to use unmanaged languages for developing an Office add-in.